# incompatible with parameter of type "int *"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is my final version for gameoflife. I have this error bug I can't fix. Please help me to solve this one:

> 1 IntelliSense: argument of type "`int (*)[50]`" is incompatible with parameter of type "`int *`"
>   line 79 `print(board, HEIGHT, WIDTH);`

```
void print(int *board, int rows, int cols) 
{
    int x, y;
    char c;
    for (y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
            if (*(board + y*cols + x) == 1)
                printf("X");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Press any key to continue:\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: Could you mark the line where the error occurs? (And preferrably indent the code sample while you're at it.)

Comment: ERROR on line 79: print(board, HEIGHT, WIDTH);

Comment: Why do you use a different parameter set for the `print` function than for all the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you are trying to pass a function an argument of type "array of 50 pointers to int" while it should be getting an argument of type "pointer to int" (which could also be an array).

In your case, the signature of your `print()` function should probably change to get an `int board[][WIDTH]` instead of `int *` which it gets now.

The change of the signature also requires a change in the function code, so the line

```
if (*(board + y*cols + x) == 1)
```

Should be changed to:

```
if (board[y][x] == 1)
```

Comment: when i chnge to void print(int board[][WIDTH], int rows, int cols) i have error:  1 IntelliSense: operand types are incompatible ("int *" and "int") on the '==' in line:  if (*(board + y*cols + x) == 1)

Comment: @Blondy21, That line should be changed to `if (board[y][x] == 1)`.

Comment: *(board + y*cols + x) is same as board[y][x] ??

Comment: when i change this to your version  i have  error - 5 IntelliSense: expected an expression on '==' if (board[y][x]) == 1)

Comment: @Blondy21, sorry, I had a typo in my answer (an extra closing parenthesis). The answer is now fixed.

Comment: @Blondy21, There was a closing parenthesis (`)`) after the `[x]` in the `if`, I removed it. The fixed `if` line is in the answer.

Comment: do you have any idea how can i stop the print when the previous generation is the same as the new...so the prints pattern is the same?

Comment: @Blondy21, You will need to copy the board before you call `step` and then compare the new and copied boards, and only print if it has changed.

Comment: PLEASE can you show me how you copy the board before the call ?

Comment: @Blondy21, That's really out of the scope of your original question. In short: create a new variable just like you did `board`, then make a nested loop like the one in `print`, and inside do `newboard[y][x] = board[y][x];`. Hope that helps. Also, if this answer helped you with your original question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @Blondy21, in `print()` you have a loop inside a loop, so those two.

Answer (score 0):

Your print function is expecting a pointer to int, but you are passing a 2-dimensional array, which decays to a pointer to a 1-dimensional array.  Either cast board to an `int*` or convert `print()` to handle a 2-d array.

Casting the call would look something like this:

```
print((int *)board, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
```

Converting `print()` to take a 2D array as argument would look something like this:

```
void print(int board[][WIDTH]) 
{
    int x, y;
    char c;
    for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            if (board[y][x] == 1)
                printf("X");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Press any key to continue:\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: when i chnge to void print(int board[][WIDTH], int rows, int cols) i have error:  1 IntelliSense: operand types are incompatible ("int *" and "int") on the '==' in line:  if (*(board + y*cols + x) == 1)

Comment: @Blondy21 if you change the declaration of the function you have to change the entire function, as you see in my answer.  The pointer arithmetic stuff doesn't work in the same way when you change the array dimension, use `if (board[y][x] == 1)` instead.

Comment: *(board + y*cols + x) is same as board[y][x] ??

Comment: @Blondy21 yes, except one works with `int *` and the other works with `int *[WIDTH]`.

Comment: when i change this to your version  i have  error - 5 IntelliSense: expected an expression on '==' if (board[y][x]) == 1)

Comment: @Blondy21 you closed the paranthesis too soon ;)

Comment: do you have any idea how can i stop the print when the previous generation is the same as the new...so the prints pattern is the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
 void print(int *board, int rows, int cols)
 ...
 int board[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
 ...
 print(board, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
```

Your `print` function first parameter is of type `int *board` but you are calling the function with an argument of type `int (*)[50]`.

You should fix your `print` function prototype (and body) to work with a parameter of the right type (i.e., `int (*)[50]`).

Comment: isnt it the same pointer? well....i plan to use dynamic matrix so user will choose the number of columns and rows...so how can i fix it?

Comment: @Blondy21 it's a pointer to the same place, but with different types.  You have to fix either the call or the function so they agree on what type is being used.

Comment: do you have any idea how can i stop the print when the previous generation is the same as the new...so the prints pattern is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Your `board` is a double array. It has both height and width. When you expect a `*board` argument in your print you actually expect an array with only one dimension. For the error to go away you have to pass `int (*board)[WIDTH]`.

When you pass a two-dimensional array to a function you have to include the size of one of the dimensions. So your `board[HEIGHT][WIDTH]` has to be passed with, at least, the information about it's width. So : `board[][WIDTH]`. You can take those empty `[]` and write them down as a pointer in front of board.

So, in your main you call your function correctly, but you have to edit your function's head to be like :

```
 void print(int (*board)[WIDTH], int rows, int cols){
```

Comment: when i chnge to void print(int *board[][WIDTH], int rows, int cols) i have error: 1 IntelliSense: operand types are incompatible ("int *" and "int") on the '==' in line: if (*(board + y*cols + x) == 1)

Comment: @Blondy21 : You will have to either use   int board[][WIDTH]  or use  int *board[WIDTH]. The [] and * symbols are the same thing in this case so by calling it as   int *board[][WIDTH]  you are actually calling a 3-dimensional array. It is equal to  int board[][][WIDTH]

Comment: do you have any idea how can i stop the print when the previous generation is the same as the new...so the prints pattern is the same?

Comment: `int board[][WIDTH]` is equivalent (as a function parameter declaration) to `int (*board)[WIDTH]`. It is not equivalent to `int *board[WIDTH]`.

Answer (score 0):

you declare

```
void print(int *board, int rows, int cols)
```

but in the the other functions you have used

```
foo(int board[][WIDTH], int rows)
```

either keep same or declare as

```
(int **board, int rows, int cols )
```

Comment: can you pass `int[][]` to `int**`?  I thought array-to-pointer conversion only worked for the leftmost array dimension?

Comment: @sverre you are right and the solution with the `int **` is not OK.

Comment: when i chnge to void print(int board[][WIDTH], int rows, int cols) i have error:  1 IntelliSense: operand types are incompatible ("int *" and "int") on the '==' in line:  if (*(board + y*cols + x) == 1)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just do like what sverre told you to, since a multidimensional array is really an abstraction the compiler provides not to do the maths you did to find the row_th and col_th element

just call it like print((int *)board, HEIGHT, WIDTH);